# How do I take a depth image from the Xbox Kinect and output the depth values to a file?

Tags: image-processing, processing, kinect, kinect-v2

I have the Xbox Kinect v2. I need to do the following:

1. Take a single depth measurement of whatever is in front of it. Think of this like taking a picture, but for depth values.
2. Output the depth values for each pixel to a file. I'm going to use these values for post processing, so I need each depth value to be associated with an x-y coordinate.

I am new to Kinect for Processing, but I am scouring the documentation and online examples now. I'm hoping someone more experienced can figure this out faster.

Answer (score 0):

With Kinectv2, I had the most success with https://github.com/shiffman/OpenKinect-for-Processing

Use the DepthPointCloud2 example as a base. (ignore the rendermode==2 portion)
then modify the if-loops as follows:

```
 StringList printer = new StringList();
 for (int x = 0; x < kinect2.depthWidth; x += skip) {
   for (int y = 0; y < kinect2.depthHeight; y += skip) {
     int offset = x + y * kinect2.depthWidth;
     PVector point = depthToPointCloudPos(x, y, depth[offset]);
     if (point.mag() != 0) {
       printer.append(point.x +","+ point.y +","+ point.z);
     }
   }
 }
 String[] printOut = printer.array();
 String path = "scan" + counter + ".xyz";
 saveStrings(path, printOut);
 println("Pointcloud :: outputted to file :: " + path);
```

Basically you set up a [StringList](https://processing.org/reference/StringList.html), then adding your xyz String to it every time it would otherwise be drawing a point, convert it to a conventional array once the scan is done, and dump it to a .txt/.xyz with [saveStrings](https://processing.org/reference/saveStrings_.html)

Might want to move the entire thing so its triggered by a KeyPressed() instead though.